# Update ContentVersion for Bulk Uploaded Files

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I have a lightning component that uses lightning file upload to tag a file at the ContentVersion level when it is uploaded. However, when bulk uploading files, only one of the documents gets tagged.

Any ideas on how I can force all to be tagged?

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="PODS_SuppDocContentVersion" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" > 

    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[
    {'label': 'Supporting Document', 'value': 'option1'},
    ]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="List" default="option1"/>


   <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default"> 
    <div class="slds-media__body"> 
        <h1 class="slds-card__header-title slds-truncate slds-align-middle--xx-small" title="Add Supporting Document"><b>Upload Supporting Document</b></h1> 

<!-- Renders the File Upload and disabled checkbox -->         
  </div>     
    <lightning:fileUpload label=" "  multiple="true" accept=".pdf, .docx, .doc" recordId="{!v.recordId}" onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}"  /> 
     <lightning:checkboxGroup name="Checkbox Group Disabled"
                             label=" "
                             options="{! v.options }"
                             value="{! v.value }"
                             disabled="true"/>
    </div> 

</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
    ({ 
    handleUploadFinished : function(component, event, helper) { 

  var action = component.get("c.updateContentVersion");
  action.setParams({recId : component.get("v.recordId") });
  $A.enqueueAction(action)

        // Get the list of uploaded files 
        var uploadedFiles = event.getParam("files"); 

        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({
            title : 'File Upload Complete',
            message: "Your supporting document, "+uploadedFiles[0].name+", has been uploaded successfully.",
            messageTemplate: 'Record {0} created! See it {1}!',
          //  duration:' 5000',
        //  key: 'info_alt',
            type: 'success',
            mode: 'sticky'
        });
        toastEvent.fire();
    }


})
```

Apex:

```
public with sharing class PODS_SuppDocContentVersion{

@AuraEnabled
    public static void updateContentVersion(String recId){
        ContentVersion[] cvs = [SELECT ID, FirstPublishLocationId, Document_Type__c FROM ContentVersion WHERE FirstPublishLocationId = :recId ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
                                Cvs[0].Document_Type__c = 'Supporting Document';
                                                update cvs[0];

    }              
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Apex server controller explicitly operates on exactly one record.

```
ContentVersion[] cvs = [SELECT ID, FirstPublishLocationId, Document_Type__c FROM ContentVersion WHERE FirstPublishLocationId = :recId ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
 Cvs[0].Document_Type__c = 'Supporting Document';
 update cvs[0];
```

If you want to update all of the uploaded documents, you would need to iterate over `cvs` and update each one, then update the list.

If you choose to do that, you'll probably want to place an additional filter on your query, such as a `CreatedDate` filter and a `CreatedById` filter, to ensure you only grab the correct versions.

Better still, grab the `ContentDocumentId` values offered in the [callback](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation):

```
({
    handleUploadFinished: function (cmp, event) {
        // Get the list of uploaded files
        var uploadedFiles = event.getParam("files");
        alert("Files uploaded : " + uploadedFiles.length);
    }
})
```

Pass these to your server controller and then query your `ContentVersion` records based on their `ContentDocumentId` being one of the created documents.